# Match Excel Spread Sheet of Addresses to State Legislator

Tags: government, address, nonprofit, district, politics

I work at a non-profit called the Georgia Justice Project.

In February, we are hosting an event called Justice Day where people from across the state will gather at the capitol to lobby with their legislators.

It is very important that each attendee knows the names of their legislators.

Is there an easy way to take a spreadsheet of addresses and match them to state legislators?

Matching by five digit zip code is not accurate as districts overlap within zip codes.

Comment: Doesn't the State of Georgia have a website that provides this information? Most states do. And there should be shapefiles of legislative districts available publicly.

Comment: If you have the 2 spreadsheets
you could use Fuzzy Lookup Add-In for Excel to do this

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011